# Is there a word or phrase for a person who is easily outraged (or fakes it) for the sake of attention in English?

Tags: phrases, expressions, figures-of-speech

This person gets agitated and outraged, so as to get attention as a moral torchbearer for an issue. Often they forget the issue and move on to next issue with out making any effort to support or resolve the issue with in few hours.

Comment: Such people are on the ascendant these days. I call them [***virtue signallers***](https://www.spectator.co.uk/2015/04/hating-the-daily-mail-is-a-substitute-for-doing-good/).

Comment: A [**choleric**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/choleric) (noun!) might fit the first part. But since you add the "for the sake of attention" it doesn't quite fit as well as **demagogue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for **demagogue**:

> a person, especially an orator or political leader, who gains power and popularity by arousing the emotions, passions, and prejudices of the people.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/demagogue)

Folks who push social ideas via outrage are said to be practicing demagoguery, which is totally a word I didn't just make up right now to win at Scrabble.

Answer (score 0):

You can call them a **poser.**  If you want to be really cutting, an exaggerated French pronunciation of *[poseur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poseur)* will help.

Answer (score 0):

You'd say they are 'virtue signalling'. It's actually the exact example of what virtue signalling means. So i guess you can call them 'virtue signallers' although i've never seen anyone use it.  Although you'd have to be careful to not overuse it because as a term it comes with some political baggage now.

https://www.spectator.co.uk/2015/10/i-invented-virtue-signalling-now-its-taking-over-the-world/

Comment: For an answer to be considered useful, it needs some justification beyond opinion. Without citing sources, there is no answer, is  opinion. .

Comment: @J.Taylor Oh! I'm like 5 minutes old at this forum. So bear with me here.

BTW the claim that it comes with political baggage is just opinion even though it is shared by quite a few people.

Comment: the comment was to help you, not to badger you.

Comment: @J.Taylor I appreciate that.